# how to align Text in Container, with the Container as small as possible?

Tags: flutter

I want to put a Text() in the center of a Container().
but When i use anything like Center Align, the Container will become as big as possible.

```
return Container(
  constraints:BoxConstraints(
    minHeight: 100,
    minWidth: 100,
  ),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  color: Color(0x4d000000),
//alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Text(
    "some message",
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
  ),
);
```

the size of the container is decided by the Text and constraints box.
if the Text size is smaller than the min constraints, the Text will not in  the center of the container.
but set alignment will cause the container fill the whole screen.

Comment: wrap the Text with a Column widget and set mainaxisalignment to center.

Comment: this is not a big dill you can solve it. use SizeBox, and For alignment use Align widget. but if you text length us more then size of box you will get overflow error so, use carefully font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give `maxWidth` & `maxHeight` in `BoxConstraints` to control Container size.

Else you can use simply use [`FittedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox-class.html) Widget - It Scales and positions its child within itself.

Wrap Container with `FittedBox`

```
FittedBox(
              child: Container(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                  minHeight: 100,
                  minWidth: 100,
                ),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                color: Color(0x4d000000),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "some message",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `textAlign` propery of the `Text` widget:

```
child: Text(
"some message",
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
,textAlign: TextAlign.center// this is what you should add
),
```

Comment: it seems to be just horizontal center,  not vertical center